# A transport vehicle with max 500lb capacity, list of passengers weighing [130, 170, 140. 100] ,shd return [130, 170] to leave exactly 300lb for safety

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, bin-packing

//java code
public static ArrayList weights(int capacity, ArrayList passangerweights) {

```
        resultList = null;
        int rem_space = 300;
        List<Integer> passangerList = passangerweights;
        int[] passangerArray = new int[passangerList.size()];


Integer[] arr = new Integer[passangerList.size()];
        arr = passangerList.toArray(arr);
//looping through passanger  list
        for (int psg : passangerList) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
                if (capacity - (arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) == rem_space) {
                    resultList.add(i, arr[i]);;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        return (ArrayList<Integer>) resultList;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering how to return the expected value? Is my code correct? I am not getting the expected output. It should return [130,170] from the list

Comment: why it should return `[130,170]`, it can also return `[140,100]`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and then make sure to read through the ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) policy article as well, because right now your question is not clear enough to answer (in fact, it doesn't even post a question, it just shows code). Please update both your question and your post to explain what you need to do, what you did, what you expected it to do, what it did instead, and what you've already tried to fix things. And the give it a title that pinpoints what you need help with, not "the entire homework exerise".

Comment: It should leave exactly 300lb capacity, not less than that. That is why it should return [130,170]

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in your code is that

```
capacity - (arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) == rem_space
```

translated into numbers looks in the first step (i==0) like following:

```
500 - (130 + 170) == 300
```

This is translated into false, since 500 - 300 != 300